# Should I use traditional 2x4 framing or 1x3 grid framing for a New England basement remodel?

Tags: basement, framing

I'm trying to decide which framing method to go with for a particular room while finishing a basement. I live in New England and I already have 2" foam board glued to the concrete using the correct foam adhesive. The concrete walls themselves are below grade. The room is roughly 11'x 19' with 2 of the 4 walls being the concrete/foam board side.

I'm planning on using this room as a home theater room with a large TV (>= 65") mounted on the side that has the 2 concrete wall/foam board. Furthermore, this wall will use sound proofing clips to mount the drywall to the frame.

Since I feel that space is at a small premium, I'm tempted to go with a 1x3 grid framing spaced at 16" on center vertically for the second layer. Would this support the weight of a TV? Would it be a good idea to use particular types of wood and not others? Are there are any other concerns I should take into account if I was to go with the 1x3 route as opposed to the traditional 2x4 route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't frame out in 1x3 especially in a basement.  It is just too flimsy and and warping with probably make it brittle.  If you want to save an inch or two (which you will never notice) then please frame in 2x3.  You won't have any issues with 2x3s (other than having to install shallow electrical boxes in some cases).

Note:  Watched the video on the grid system.  I am sorry but this just seems *very ill advised* to me.  I have a list of problems I have with it (these are just some off the top of my head):

- it's not faster or cheaper than installing traditional 2x3 (2x4) walls
- it saves you maybe 1/2 inch per wall.
- my biggest peeve is that you are drilling tons of holes in your foundation.  I just can't believe someone would do this
- your insulation is now a support structure since your 1x3 will bend and rest on it
- not even sure if running romex behind would be code (doubt it would get passed in my area)
- basement walls usually aren't flat (and if they are they don't usually stay flat).  So when framing I pop out at the bulge you would just be drywalling there.

Comment: I'm not sure if I provided a good description of what I was thinking of doing with 1x3s. This video explains it a lot better: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oKQdo88Ne74#t=381

Comment: +1 for content, but *retarded* is a term that is considered by many as disrespectful of individuals with developmental disabilities. Perhaps *very ill advised* instead? Or even *stupid*?

Comment: @bib - I was going for the definition of "Socially inappropriate or foolish."  I will change it so that you can sleep better.

Comment: Drilling the holes in the concrete will not weaken it at all.  One benefit of the foam over the 2x4 method is that the insulation is continuous, and foam also provides a vapour barrier.

Comment: @Mark - I agree but holes will not "weaken" the concrete.  However it will make it easier for a small crack to leak.